# Inequality and convex combination

Tags: analysis, inequality, convex-analysis

Suppose that $\lambda_{i}\geq 0$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}{\lambda_{i}}=1$. Does it hold that $$|\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}{\lambda_{i}x_{i}}|+\sum_{i=1}^{n}{\lambda_{i}|x_{i}|}\geq \lambda_{n+1}|x_{n+1}|$$?

Comment: Try to use the triangle inequality.

Comment: Can you please be more explicit?

Comment: @ShaqAttack1337: Use two times and both side of the triangle inequality (see my answer)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\hspace{-75pt}\Big|\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}{\lambda_{i}x_{i}}\Big|+\sum_{i=1}^{n}{\lambda_{i}|x_{i}|} &\geq  |\lambda_{n+1}x_{n+1} |-\Big|\sum_{i=1}^{n}{\lambda_{i}x_{i}}\Big|+\sum_{i=1}^{n}{\lambda_{i}|x_{i}|}\tag{since $|a+b|\geq |a|-|b|$ }\\
& =|\lambda_{n+1}x_{n+1} |+\underbrace{\sum_{i=1}^{n}{\lambda_{i}|x_{i}|}-\sum_{i=1}^{n}{\lambda_{i}|x_{i}}}_{\geq 0}| \\
&\geq |\lambda_{n+1}x_{n+1} | = \lambda_{n+1}|x_{n+1} |
\end{align*}

Notice that the convex sum is not needed...

Comment: Thanks, great answer!